# Time in axis X - GraphView for android

Tags: android, android-graphview

```
// generate Dates
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date d1 = calendar.getTime();
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
Date d2 = calendar.getTime();
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
Date d3 = calendar.getTime();

GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

// you can directly pass Date objects to DataPoint-Constructor
// this will convert the Date to double via Date#getTime()
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>(new DataPoint[] {
    new DataPoint(d1, 1),
    new DataPoint(d2, 5),
    new DataPoint(d3, 3)
});
graph.addSeries(series);

// set date label formatter
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(getActivity()));
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(3); // only 4 because of the space

// set manual x bounds to have nice steps
graph.getViewport().setMinX(d1.getTime());
graph.getViewport().setMaxX(d3.getTime());
graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
```

**When use one Second as XAxis Graph is not displaying. but if use more than 60 seconds then graph is displaying. I dont know the reason. Anyone have similar problem with GRaphView.**

Answer (score 0):

use the latest version of the library and try to use this:

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(false);
```